# command to check used Journal space MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

whats the command in mongo to check current Journal space used or whats the limit set

using Mongo version 3.2.8 and storage engine wiredTiger

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/1179130/command-to-check-current-journal-space-used-in-mongo). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the Journal space used by Mongo?

> MongoDB uses a journal file size limit of 100 MB, WiredTiger creates a new journal file approximately every 100 MB of data. When WiredTiger creates a new journal file, WiredTiger syncs the previous journal file.

Source [Journaling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/)

---

#### How can I reduce the Journal file size?

> Yes - there is a way to minimize the default size of the journal
>   files, subject to a couple of caveats. From the [MongoDB configuration
>   documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/):
>
> > To reduce the impact of the journaling on disk usage, you can leave journal enabled, and set smallfiles to true to reduce the size of the
> >     data and journal files.
>
> Here is the `smallfiles` config information:
>
> > Set to true to modify MongoDB to use a smaller default data file size. Specifically, smallfiles reduces the initial size for data files
> >     and limits them to 512 megabytes. The smallfiles setting also reduces
> >     the size of each journal files from 1 gigabyte to 128 megabytes.
> >
> > Use the smallfiles setting if you have a large number of databases that each hold a small quantity of data. The smallfiles setting can
> >     lead mongod to create many files, which may affect performance for
> >     larger databases.

Source [Run a MongoDB configuration server without 3GB of journal files](https://serverfault.com/questions/329574/run-a-mongodb-configuration-server-without-3gb-of-journal-files), answer by [platforms](https://serverfault.com/users/144450/platforms)

Comment: the question is wats the command to check the current total space used by Journal

Comment: @shiv455 The journal files are preallocated.